# Convert a curl query to jQuery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl, coldfusion

I have a curl command that work fine. It's a query to a coldfusion server that  returns a WDDX :

```
curl --user 'adminUser:adminPass' 'http://blablabla/app.cfc?method=isSusbscribed&newsletterId=2222&language=en&email=anemal@mail.com'
```

The result is  :

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><boolean value='true'/></data></wddxPacket>
```

This means that the user with the given email receive the newsletter with the id 2222.

Now, I'm trying to write the same command but with Ajax in a js script :

I have tried to do this :

```
$.ajax({url:'http://blablabla/app.cfc?method=isSusbscribed&newsletterId=2222&language=en&email=anemal@mail.com'
,username:'adminUser'
,password:'adminPass'})
      .done(function(res){
        jRes=$(res).find('boolean[value]');
        if(jRes.length == 1) inputElem.prop('checked', jRes.attr('value')=='true'); 
      }).always(function(res,text){
        console.log(res);
        console.log(text);
      })
      ;
```

but it doesn't work.

My goal is to put a switch in the ON position if the user is registered to a newsletter.

Probably the syntax of the query is not correct and I think the problem is  related to authentication.

Can somebody help me? 
Thanks

Comment: Why would you not make that call on the server? Seems like a bad idea to have the hardcoded username and password out in the public eyes?

Comment: For now, it is only a test code. Users credentials will not be hard-coded. I just need to know the correct syntax.

Comment: Also is it a cross domain call? Because that leads to other issues if they do not support CORS.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? What happens? What is different than what is expected? IT will probably be easier to use the data returned if you return it as JSON rather than the WDDX that you showed. You can simply add `&returnFormat=JSON` to the URL in your AJAX call.

Comment: the console.log(res) returns an empty object, the console.log(text) returns "error" and the the switch is not changed as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure when you do `--user` in a curl request then it's using Basic Authentication. So you need to use Basic Authentication in your jQuery call. You will also need to Base64 encode your username and password. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'...',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW5Vc2VyOmFkbWluUGFzcw==");
  }
}).done(function(res){
  // handle success...
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. I tried this :
   ` $.ajax({
     url: 'http:.....&returnFormat=JSON',
     beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa("user:pass"); 
   // or this xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic user:pass"); 
     },
     success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
     },
     error: function(){
        alert("Cannot get data");
     }
 });`
and I get the error.

Comment: In the console I have this message (as suggested by epascarello)

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote
resource at http://...&returnFormat=JSON&_=1428501028107. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

But I am confused because if I directly put the url in the browser and give the username and password, 
I get the value expected, so cannot be a problem with the CORS (?).

What am I missing ?

Comment: Ah - so it is a CORS issue. Your browser is restricted so the JavaScript can only access the same domain as the parent web page. This is done for security reasons (XSS attacks). When you run it manually you are not using JavaScript to request it.